# How to post to the Instagram API?

Tags: php, json, curl, instagram

Trying to return a JSON decode of an API curl on instagram, but it's only returning a blank page.

```
<?php
$instagram_username = "devrXXXXXX";
$instagram_client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$instagram_client_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$instagram_redirect_uri = 'http://production.devr.me/XXXXXXXXX/index.php';
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
$access_token_parameters = array(
    'client_id'     =>     $instagram_client_id,
    'client_secret'     =>     $instagram_client_secret,
    'grant_type'        =>     'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri'      =>     $instagram_redirect_uri,
    'code'          =>     $_GET["code"]
);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$access_token_parameters);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$instagram_json = curl_exec($curl);

$instagram_string = json_decode($instagram_json);
echo $instagram_string;
?>
```

Comment: Do you need to post the data as JSON and not an array?

Comment: I can handle it as an array, which was my expected result, but I'm just getting a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably generate a warning at the very least if not an error, something like:

```
Warning Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.
```

Try:

```
var_dump($instagram_string);
```

Instead of:

```
echo $instagram_string;
```

If you want to echo the string then:

```
echo $instagram_json;
```